# Why Angular use attribute selector for css encapsulation

Tags: html, css, angular

In Angular(2+), component's CSS are encapsulated by attribute selector.

e.g. When I wrote the following CSS,

```
 .myClass     { ... }
 div          { ... }
 div.myClass  { ... }
 div .myClass { ... }
```

then Angular compiles as following

```
 .myClass[_ngcontent-htp-42]     { ... }
 div[_ngcontent-htp-42]          { ... }
 div.myClass[_ngcontent-htp-42]  { ... }
 div[_ngcontent-htp-42] .myClass[_ngcontent-htp-42]{ ... }
```

Why?

I understand importance of encapsulation.
However, I think that it is also possible to use css-class. Like this

```
 ._ngcontent-htp-42 .myClass     { ... }
 ._ngcontent-htp-42 div          { ... }
 ._ngcontent-htp-42 div.myClass  { ... }
 ._ngcontent-htp-42 div .myClass { ... }
```

What are the advantages of using attribute selector?

Comment: Good question. In Dart they just switched to classes instead of attributes because it's sometimes faster. I also remember that Polymer started with using attributes a lot and than also switched to classes for performance reasons. I guess they used attributes because they are a bit more pleasant to look at.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Could it also be that because they use attributes, the compiled version of the application is a tad smaller? Instead of `<div class="_ngcontent">`, it's just `<div _ngcontent>`. With a lot of templates, I would guess it matters a bit. And inside the css, they save one character as well ;). And what happens if you add `@HostBinding('class')` to a component. Doesn't that override the encapsulation class?

Comment: It's possible. I'm not sure about `@HostBinding('class')`. I only used `class.foo` or `ngClass` so far.I try to avoid binding to `class` directly.